# Angular 2: how to conditionally apply attribute directive?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, dragula

I use drag&drop via [ng2-dragula](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula).
The drag&drop functionality is applied this way:

```
<div class='container' [dragula]='"first-bag"'>
    <div>item 1</div>
    <div>item 2</div>
</div>
```

If I understand angular 2 properly, the way how `[dragula]='"first-bag"'` is attached to my div is called [Attribute Directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) in Angular 2.

Now I have a variable in my component called `enableDragNDrop:boolean`. How can I use this variable to attach `[dragula]='"first-bag"'` to my div only when `enableDragNDrop == true` ?

If `enableDragNDrop  == false`, i want this:

```
<div class='container'><!-- no dragula attribute directive, no dragndrop -->
    <div>item 1</div>
    <div>item 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to dynamically add/remove directives by adding/removing a selector. The selector `dragula` has to be static HTML for the directive to get applied. You can only use features of dragula to enable/disable it if it provides such a configuration option.

I haven't used `ng2-dragula` or `dragula` but I guess you can assign a `dragModel` and configure it this way

```
<div class='container' dragula [dragulaModel]="dragulaModel">
```

```
dragulaModel = {start: function () {}};
```

and when you want to enable it, assign a model that doesn't disable start

```
enableDrag() {
  this.dragulaModel = {};
}
```

Not tested, just skimmed a bit through the source.

Comment: thanks for reply. when `dragulaModel = {start: function () {}};`, drag&drop is allowed, and when item is moved and droped, following error is thrown: `TypeError: sourceModel.splice is not a function`.

Btw, there are two approaches how to deal with the issue: 

one is to completely prevent drag&drop from happening - so far we don't know how to do this. 

Second approach is that drag&drop is possible, but the results are not stored, i.e. `if(enableDragNDrop) this.dragulaService.dropModel.subscribe(this.myCustomOnDropCallback.bind(this))`

Comment: I don't plan to dive deeper into this topic because I currently don't plan to use dragula myself. I just tried to help from an Angular point-of-view. I might get better results by asking about dragula specifically without mentioning Angular.

Comment: ok, I found one approach how to conditionally completely disable drag&drop in angular 2 in dragula, and that is to use [moves callback](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula#optionsmoves) to allow move only when moved dom element has a particular css -- this css class is assigned to draggable element by angular 2 only when `enableDragNDrop == true`.

Comment: That sounds promising.