# How do I conditionally add mat-raised-button?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a button on my screen where if the user has already added clicked on it, it is a **mat-filled-button** but if I haven't clicked on it, it is a **mat-button**

My code looks like this

```
 <button
          *ngIf="myVote !== 'UPVOTE'"
          mat-button
          color="primary"
          (click)="onVote('UPVOTE')"
        >
          UPVOTE
        </button>
        <button
          *ngIf="myVote === 'UPVOTE'"
          mat-flat-button
          color="primary"
          (click)="onVote('NONE')"
        >
          UPVOTE
        </button>
```

Basically I have two buttons and only one shows. Obviously, this is very ugly.

Is there a way where I can achieve the same outcome with only one button and it conditionally is a `mat-flat-button` or a `mat-button` based on a set of logic?

Comment: these might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597077/apply-a-directive-conditionally
and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021355/angular-2-how-to-conditionally-apply-attribute-directive

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2/36745752

Comment: Why not use button toggle instead: https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/overview?

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Comment: As of today (angular 15) no good solution does exists. [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/15367) if you wish to follow the github feature request

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<button
  mat-button 
  [class.mat-flat-button]="myVote === 'UPVOTE'"
  color="primary"
  (click)="onVote(myVote === 'UPVOTE'? 'NONE' :'UPVOTE')"
>
  UPVOTE
</button>
```

See [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-hkppdz)

_ I have used raised button the demo for better visibility.

Comment: just wondering why is it mat-button and not [class.mat-button]="myVote !== 'UPVOTE'"?

Comment: Because you want to have the mat-button displayed even when myVote isn't set

Comment: I think that a more sustainable and easier to maintain route is to use `[ngClass ]`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the accepted answer would be to use `[ngClass]`. Making use of `ngClass` gives you more flexibility and control for future changing requirements.

Taking the answer and just modifying it to use `ngClass` instead would look like this:

```
<button
  mat-button 
  [ngClass]="{'mat-flat-button': myVote === 'UPVOTE'}"
  color="primary"
  (click)="onVote(myVote === 'UPVOTE'? 'NONE' :'UPVOTE')"
>
  UPVOTE
</button>
```

The reason I would recommend this over simply using the `[class]` attribute, is it makes it easier if you want to apply new conditions to the button in the future. For example, you want a different `mat` class when the upvote is `'NONE'`

You can now easily just add to the object and it becomes:

```
<button
  mat-button 
  [ngClass]="{'mat-flat-button': myVote === 'UPVOTE', 'mat-stroked-button': myVote === 'NONE'}"
  color="primary"
  (click)="onVote(myVote === 'UPVOTE'? 'NONE' :'UPVOTE')"
>
  UPVOTE
</button>
```

See the documentation for `ngClass` here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score -1):

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36745752/1471485

You could do something like this:

```
<button
  [attr.mat-button]="myVote !== 'UPVOTE'"
  [attr.mat-flat-button]="myVote === 'UPVOTE'"
  color="primary"
  (click)="onVote()"> <!-- Alternate the vote in the function -->
  UPVOTE
</button>

onVote(){
   if(this.myVote === 'UPVOTE') this.myVote = 'NONE';
   else this.myVote = 'UPVOTE';
}
```

Comment: Hi, so I think conceptually your answer is better than Adrita Sharma's answer - she is updating the class which basically requires an understanding of what mat-button and mat-flat-button is doing under the surface. However, your answer doesn't actually work because mat-button and mat-flat-button are selectors within the MatButton component which I don't think you can make conditional...

Comment: i dunno, i'm just looking through https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/button/button.ts now but it does seem like it only checks to see if that selector is there and if so, adds a class

Comment: with `[attr.mat-button]` & `[attr.mat-icon-button]` it does not work, unfortunately. For example there are some directives which work with this notation like `[attr.mat-align-tabs] ` but mat-button not work.